# Ajuda com API Instagram

Tags: javascript, asp, instagram-api

Estou tentando **consumir** a **API** do **Instagram** e observei aqui na **comunidade Stackoverflow** sobre a **biblioteca** denominada **Instafeed.JS**, com isto segui a documentação oficial da mesma em seu repositório github.

Já possuo o cadastro no site oficial do [Instagram Developer](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) e com isto possuo a **`id_client`**, **`secret key`** e o **`token`**, porém não estou conseguindo consumir a mesma. **Segue o meu código abaixo:**

**ASP**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%--
    This file is an entry point for JavaServer Faces application.
--%>
<f:view>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-    8"/>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="instafeed.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
            <title>JSP Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1><h:outputText value="JSF e Jsp"/></h1>
            <button onclick="doAPI()">Fornecer Client ID e rodar</button>
            <br />
            <h3>Rock Tag</h3>
                <div id="rockTag"></div>
            <h3>Glass Tag</h3>
                <div id="glassTag"></div>
            <h3>Wood Tag</h3>
                <div id="woodTag"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
</f:view>
```

**JS**

```
function getMultipleTags (tags,client) {
    var feeds = [];
    for (var i=0, len=tags.length; i < len; i++) {
        feeds.push(new Instafeed({
            // rest of your options
            get: 'tagged',
            tagName: tags[i],
            target: tags[i] + "Tag",
            limit: 3,
            clientId: client,
            template: '<div class="insta-pic"><a href="{{link}}"><img src="    {{image}}" /></a></div>'
        }));
    }
    return feeds;
}
function doAPI() {
     var  client = window.prompt("Sua ID:", '');
     if( client ) {
        // get multiple tags
        var myTags = getMultipleTags(['glass', 'wood', 'rock'],client);
        // run each instance
        for(var i=0, len=myTags.length; i < len; i++) {
            myTags[i].run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A API Aparentemente não respondeu nada.

Comment: O Instagram fez uma modificação em sua API onde todas as aplicações foram movidas para o Sandbox mode. Existe [uma issue no github](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/issues/408) e você pode aprender mais sobre isso na [página oficial do sandbox mode](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/).

Comment: o instagram fechou vários endpoints de sua API, restando apenas a opção do user que aceitar seu APP a obter suas próprias fotos, me diz o que esta querendo fazer pra ver se eu consigo ajudar!

Comment: O que o @RafaelCavalcante disse é verdade, eu analisei na documentação [oficial da API do Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) e já te inseri como resposta. Peço por gentileza para ler arduamente sobre [como criar uma boa pergunta aqui na comunidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), pois ficou faltando realmente qual problema ocorreu, você apenas postou o código e não detalhou e elaborou a questão corretamente.

Answer (score 3):

De acordo com o **[site oficial](https://www.instagram.com/developer/)** da **API** do **instagram** eles dizem o seguinte em uma nota:

> Para melhorar continuamente a privacidade e a segurança dos usuários do Instagram, estamos acelerando a depreciação do Instagram API Platform, fazendo as seguintes alterações entrarem em vigor imediatamente. Entendemos que isso pode afetar seus negócios ou serviços e agradecemos seu apoio para manter nossa plataforma segura.
>
> Esses [recursos](https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/) serão desativados imediatamente (anteriormente definido para 31 de julho de 2018 ou 11 de dezembro de 2018, com descontinuidade). O seguinte será suspenso de acordo com a linha do tempo que [compartilhamos anteriormente](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/01/30/instagram-graph-api-updates/) :
>
> Conteúdo público - todos os recursos restantes para ler mídia pública em nome de um usuário em 11 de dezembro de 2018 Básico - para ler as informações do perfil do usuário e mídia no início de 2020. Para sua referência, informações sobre a [nova API de gráficos do Instagram](https://developers.facebook.com/products/instagram/).

**Para iniciar as requisições a *API* você deve seguir os passos:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O **último commit** de acordo com o ***github oficial da biblioteca citada*** foi na seguinte data: **Sep 6, 2018**. Logo o **Instagram** anunciou a **depreciação** na data de: **July 31, 2018 ou December 11, 2018**. Por isto por questão de **segurança**, **compatibilidade**, **manutenção** entre outros eu sugiro que ***deixei de utilizar*** a **biblioteca Instafeed.JS** e ***estude bastante*** a [documentação oficial da API do instagram](https://www.instagram.com/developer/), para poder criar o seu sistema e/ou aplicativo mobile e até mesmo para poder elaborar um plano de arquitetura do mesmo.